# Why my STYLE to import external font-face doesn't work

Tags: html, css, font-face, webfonts

Why doesn't the following `<style>` change my font to "Computer Modern Typewriter"?

The URL is effective.

```
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Computer Modern Typewriter';
        src: url('http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cm-unicode/fonts/otf/cmuntt.otf');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    body {
        font-size: 1em;
        font-family: 'Computer Modern Typewriter'
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Is your page being served over https?

Comment: Maybe you wrote inline CSS code for elements of the body. Inline CSS is the priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link you provided doesn't support HTTPS, so if your site have HTTPS connection and headers which restrict access to unsecured HTTP it's can be the problem.

Also, OpenType isn't so suitable for web now, you can use WOFF or WOFF2 version of the same font. I found one here: https://github.com/dreampulse/computer-modern-web-font. Use it like this:

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Computer Modern Typewriter';
 src: url('cmuntt.eot');
 src: url('cmuntt.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   url('cmuntt.woff') format('woff'),
   url('cmuntt.ttf') format('truetype'),
   url('cmuntt.svg#cmuntt') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: 'Computer Modern Typewriter';
 src: url('cmuntb.eot');
 src: url('cmuntb.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   url('cmuntb.woff') format('woff'),
   url('cmuntb.ttf') format('truetype'),
   url('cmuntb.svg#cmuntb') format('svg');
 font-weight: bold;
 font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: 'Computer Modern Typewriter';
 src: url('cmunit.eot');
 src: url('cmunit.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   url('cmunit.woff') format('woff'),
   url('cmunit.ttf') format('truetype'),
   url('cmunit.svg#cmunit') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: 'Computer Modern Typewriter';
 src: url('cmuntx.eot');
 src: url('cmuntx.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   url('cmuntx.woff') format('woff'),
   url('cmuntx.ttf') format('truetype'),
   url('cmuntx.svg#cmuntx') format('svg');
 font-weight: bold;
 font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: Remember to replace file links to your own site or CDN.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css

```css
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Computer Modern";
            src: url('http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cm-unicode/fonts/otf/cmunss.otf');
        }        
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Computer Modern";
            src: url('http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cm-unicode/fonts/otf/cmunsx.otf');
            font-weight: bold;
        }        
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Computer Modern";
            src: url('http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cm-unicode/fonts/otf/cmunsi.otf');
            font-style: italic, oblique;
        }        
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Computer Modern";
            src: url('http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cm-unicode/fonts/otf/cmunbxo.otf');
            font-weight: bold;
            font-style: italic, oblique;
        }        
        body {
            font-family: "Computer Modern", sans-serif;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because that's an OTF font.

You should get or create other font formats - you mainly need the WOFF format for websites.

If the font allows it (copyright-wise) you can create that here: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Answer (score 0):

Just `.otf` is not enough. 
You've to add other formats as well.. check [here](https://onlinefontconverter.com). For you ease just click check fontface and necessary formats will be made available. Also, check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) how to add multiple `src` for `font-face`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not OTF problem, it is with the URL
`http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cm-unicode/fonts/otf/cmuntt.otf`
Althoght it is accessible but it's NOT HTTPS and the browser doesn't load it.
I saved a copy to GitHub and then applied the same STYLE (with URL replaced to new https url). It worked!